# Django local server error

Tags: python, django

I started learning django and just deployed my first app when this showed up.
Any suggestions would be useful.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgMjG.png)

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
  from django.conf.urls import url
```

(without `s` at the end)

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your import, it should be:

`from django.conf.urls import url`

ref:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/